# choosing the best pose for multiple people in a burst of similar photos

Tags: image-processing, photo-editing

When I'm taking a photo of multiple people I usually take a bunch of quick photos in rapid succession in hopes that one of them will come out with everyone looking good. Not blinking, smiling if that's the thing, etc.

Anyone know of a command-line or GUI tool on Ubuntu to do this kind of smart photo editing? I'm aware of manual bitmap image editors like The Gimp, but I guess I'm looking for something a little easier to use just for this purpose.

I'm wondering if there's a tool for this specific purpose, not "which tool is the best". Hopefully that's the more objective thing to be asking here.

Comment: Any Pixel phone can do it. See [this story](https://lifehacker-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/lifehacker.com/your-pixel-will-now-wait-until-everyone-is-smiling-befo-1848131573/amp?amp_gsa=1&amp_js_v=a9&usqp=mq331AQKKAFQArABIIACAw%3D%3D#amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&aoh=16544725371247&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Flifehacker.com%2Fyour-pixel-will-now-wait-until-everyone-is-smiling-befo-1848131573)

Comment: You could build something [similar to this](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/07/14/smile-detection-with-opencv-keras-and-tensorflow/) (although it uses video instead of photos).

Comment: @mchid I was thinking of something similar. Things get a bit more complicated for group photos/videos and when the code needs to look for two targets such as smiles and "not blinking" in multiple faces. Getting a large enough training data (collection of videos of "group photos" is another issue.